# Minimize Energy in Image processing - Geodesic active contours

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, image-processing, geodesic

I've read some papers in Geodesic active contours (Image processing), which use the minimization of an Energy, consist of Internal Energy and External energy, for example, in the paper of Kass (Snake: Active contour model - 1988), we have the following formula

$$E_{snake} = \int_0^1 (E_{int}(v(s))+E_{image}(v(s))+E_{con}(v(s)))ds $$

with $v(s) = (x(s),y(s))$ and $E_{int} = \frac{1}{2}(\alpha(s)|v_s(s)|^2+\beta(s)|v_{ss}(s)|^2)$. In the paper, they have the first term makes the snake act like a membrane and the second term makes it act like a thin-plate. I don't know how they derive the fomula $E_{int}$, and so the $E_{con}, E_{image}$ like that. What is it and where does it come from? In mechanic ? or another related field? 
Thanks in advance. Please forgive me if I had some grammatical mistakes.

Comment: The snake is a hugger snake. Now this is no biology site, but basically the snake wants to hug and squeeze it's prey in order to kill it so that it can be eaten. The prey's resistance are commonly taken to be the absolute values of the gradients in the image or some remapping thereof. The snake keeps squeezing until the hugger-forces excerted by the snake and the forces of resistance acting on the snake (from it's prey) end up in an equilibrium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes from very idealized continuum mechanics: squared first derivative is elastic energy, squared second derivative is bending energy.

To simplify things, I'll consider scalar function $x(s)$, since the contributions of both $x$ and $y$ components are simply added together in your formula. The length of the graph $x(s)$ is 
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(x'(s))^2}\,ds 
$$
which for small values of derivative can be approximated by 
$$
\frac12 \int_0^1  (x'(s))^2\,ds  \tag1
$$
Minimization of the functional (1) among curves constrained to pass through given points creates a piecewise linear function: this is what we get by tightening an elastic string that is nailed to a wall in a few places.

[image: pl interpolation]

The bending energy, whatever it is, should depend on the curvature of the graph. the curvature is related to second derivative. So,
$$
\int_0^1  (x''(s))^2\,ds\to \min  \tag2
$$
becomes an idealized  model of a string that resists bending. Minimization of (2) with the same conditions as above leads to a pleasantly curved graph, which passes through the given points without sharp turns (sharp turns would mean rapid change of first derivative, hence large second derivative).

[image: spline]

(Both images are from my post [Connecting dots naturally](http://calculus7.org/2014/02/14/connecting-dots-naturally/).)

Comment: Thank you very much, it really makes sense. I think I can understand your idea but I still have some problems. Why it is an elastic energy ? Suppose we have a string, represented by a graph of $v(s)$, s is a parameter, and it has elastic properties. Could you give me some detail or references to show how to derive the energy fomula $\int (u'(s))^2ds$

Comment: @user284630 Yes, "elastic" is too vague a word. I meant the potential energy of the stretched out string. It is *modeled* by $\int (v')^2$, e.g., [here](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~grigoryan/124A/lecs/lec7.pdf).

Comment: I got it, but just another question about the bending energy, how to derive it ? I know the meaning why the curvature are related to it (because the curvature measure how a curve change direction), but I need some more detail. I found out something like this formula $\int \kappa^2 \|x'(t)\|dt $ and then they say that we have an approximation $\int \|x''(t)\|^2dt \approx \int \kappa^2 \|x'(t)\|dt$.

Comment: @genov4 Yes, bending energy is taken proportional to the square of curvature, as [explained here](http://www.uic.edu/classes/phys/phys450/MARKO/N014.html). For the graph of $y=f(x)$ the curvature is $y''/(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}$. Assuming relatively small deviation from horizontal, we can say that the denominator is $\approx 1$.

Comment: Regarding to that approximation, the bending energy is $\int \kappa^2 dt$, or $\int \kappa^2\|x'(t)\|dt$, which is the right formula ? I think the $\int \kappa^2dt$ must be right, isn't it ? But I found in some notes they use $\int \kappa^2 \|x'(t)\|dt$, are they wrong? 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: ah, why the first derivative $\|x′(t)\|$ is very small ? Is it because of the bend of the graph ? At the bend of the graph, two point on the graph which have the same $y_1=y_2$, with $y_1=f(x_1)$, $y_2=f(x_2)$, so the "approximate" derivative $\frac{y1−y2}{x1−x2}=0$, therefore the derivative is small (is it why you say that " Assuming relatively small deviation from horizontal" ?). Thanks :)

Comment: @genov4 Ultimately, the answer is: because we want a simple model, that's the main reason. To have a linear Euler-Lagrange equation, we need a quadratic energy functional: something with squares of derivatives, but without quotients, square roots, etc. So, we take the square of second derivative because that's the derivative related to curvature (bending). Then one puts various justifications around this choice, saying that under certain assumptions it does not look totally wrong. I would not want a bridge built on the basis of such models. But as an analogy for image processing algo, why not.

Comment: Now I understand why they chose that equation, and about my comment above, is it right ? I've just started learning this project for few days ago. Thanks to your answer I know a lot of new things, thank you very much :)

Comment: @genov4 It is right in the sense that when the bending is slight, first derivative is small. Then one goes ahead and applies the model even when the first derivative is not small, just because it still kind of works.

Comment: It really help me a lot, now I can think about it clearly. Thanks.  :)